# How to transfer linear map into a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone explain me how I can transfer a linear map into a matrix ? I found some examples on the internet but i cannot understand them, as they are too simple and I have to solve more abstract problems like

> $f$: $\mathbb{R^n}$ ->$\mathbb{R}$, $f$($x$):=$\langle x,a\rangle$, for $a$ ∈ $\mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: The key is that the columns are the images of the basis vectors.

Comment: Your problem is written strangely.  If $f(x):= \langle x,a \rangle$, then $f$ would be a map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$, whereas you have written $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

If $M = (m_{ij})$ is the $m \times n$ matrix of our map $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ relative to the standard bases $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$, then the coefficients $m_{ij}$ satisfy
$$
f(e_j) = \sum_{i=1}^m m_{ij}e_i
$$
For instance: in order to find column $2$ of the matrix $M$ of your map (for which $m = 1$), we need a coefficient $m_{12}$ such that
$$
f(e_2) = m_{12} 
$$
That is, the second column of your matrix $M$ will simply be the entry $m_{12} = f(e_2) = \langle a, e_2 \rangle = a_2$.